# Issue with scoping, when calling a function in a callback

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, easeljs, createjs

when clicking inside the canvas it will generate a ball and move to the clicked location
when the ball get's to its location I want it to remove itself. But i think i have a problem
with the scope when calling the removeBall() function.

You can find a working example her: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7RcKj/1/)

```
 /*
  * Main app logic
  */
  function Main() {
    this.canvas = "canvas";
    this.stage = null;
    this.WIDTH = 0;
    this.HEIGHT = 0;
    this.init();
  }

  Main.prototype.init = function() {
    console.clear();
    this.stage = new createjs.Stage(this.canvas);
    this.resize();
    //start game loop
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", this.gameLoop);
    //click event handler
    this.stage.on("stagemousedown", function(evt) {
      main.fireBall(evt);
    });
  };

  Main.prototype.fireBall = function(evt) {
    var bal = new Bal(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);
  };

  Main.prototype.resize = function() {
    //resize the canvas to take max width
    this.WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
    this.HEIGHT = Math.floor(window.innerWidth * 9 / 16);
    this.stage.canvas.width = this.WIDTH;
    this.stage.canvas.height = this.HEIGHT;
  };

  Main.prototype.gameLoop = function() {
    //game loop
    main.stage.update();
  };

  /*
   * Ball logic
  */
  function Bal(toX, toY) {
    this.toX = toX ;
    this.toY = toY;
    this.widthPerc = 8;
    this.init();
  }

  Bal.prototype.width = function() {
    return Math.floor(main.stage.canvas.width / 100 * this.widthPerc);
  };

  Bal.prototype.init = function() {
    //create a new ball
    this.ball = new createjs.Shape();
    this.ball.graphics.beginFill("green").drawCircle(0, 0, this.width());
    this.ball.x = (main.stage.canvas.width / 2) - (this.width() / 2);
    this.ball.y = main.stage.canvas.height - 20;
    main.stage.addChild(this.ball);    
    this.move();
  };

  Bal.prototype.move = function() {
    //create a tween to cliked coordinates
    createjs.Tween.get(this.ball).to({
        x: this.toX ,
        y: this.toY ,
        scaleX:0.4,scaleY:0.4,
        rotation: 180
      },
      750, //speed
      createjs.Ease.none
    ).call(this.removeBall); //   <---- How can i pass the correct scope to the called function?
  };

  Bal.prototype.removeBall = function() {
    //try to remove the ball
    main.stage.removeChild(this.ball);
  };

  var main = new Main();
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution above using bind works, however there is a much better solution. Bind is not available in all browsers (most notably Safari 5.1, which is a modern browser). http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/#Function.prototype.bind

TweenJS has built-in support for scoping functions when using `call()`. Just pass the scope as the 3rd argument.

```
Ball.prototype.move = function() {
  console.log(this.toX +","+this.toY);
  createjs.Tween.get(this.ball).to({
      x: this.toX ,
      y: this.toY ,
      scaleX:0.4,scaleY:0.4,
      rotation: 180
    },
    750, //speed
    createjs.Ease.none
  ).call(this.removeBall, null, this);
};
```

You can also pass an array of function arguments as the second parameter.

```
Tween.call(this.removeBall, [this.ball], this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok found a solution! using the bind() functionality.

```
Bal.prototype.move = function() {
  console.log(this.toX +","+this.toY);
  createjs.Tween.get(this.ball).to({
      x: this.toX ,
      y: this.toY ,
      scaleX:0.4,scaleY:0.4,
      rotation: 180
    },
    750, //speed
    createjs.Ease.none
  ).call(this.removeBall.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: `animationDone` is not there in your question at all.

Comment: My bad, fixed the typo.